# Rank advertisement and Score keywords used in advertisement based on its performance

Tags: python, classification, regression, data-science-model, normalization

I am trying to classify my advertisements and trying to understand which advertisement is performing better than others and why.

**Step - 1**: compare two ads based on CTR.
The problem here is I am basically comparing 2 advertisements with different impressions, for example, ad-1 is having 100 impressions and 25% CTR, whereas ad-2 is having 50 impressions but 10% CTR, here I cannot compare both directly because ad-1 has got more CTR because the impressions are more(which means we have shown this more number of times), we can use basic math and try to figure for ad-2 by multiplying by 2 and making it for 100 impressions but is there a better way that we could potentially forecast the ad-2 based on impressions and predict CTR.

**Step - 2**: score the keywords in each.
Here I am trying to score the keyword and tagline used in the image of ads(I have extracted them using AWS rekognition) but what is a good data science technique to score the taglines?

sample dataset -

**ad-1**

Date -  ad name -   audience type - ad type -   Impressions -   Clicks  - Conersions -  Taglines

02-12-2020  advertisement 1 sports  generic 10000   100 50  (Play like star, It's never late, Dont give up)

03-12-2020  advertisement 1 sports  generic 10000   130 60  (Play like star, It's never late, Dont give up)

**ad -2**

Date -  ad name -   audience type - ad type -   Impressions -   Clicks  - Conersions -  Taglines

02-12-2020  advertisement 2 Kids    generic 5000    100 40  (Whatever it takes, Play like a champion)

03-12-2020  advertisement 2 Kids    generic 4000    50  10  (Whatever it takes, Play like a champion)

Here is a screenshot of the data mentioned above

[image: Here is a screenshot of sample data]

Can someone please guide me on this